# How do I run Homebrew as root?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, homebrew

Years ago, you could get away with running `brew` as root just by chowning `brew` to root, but they removed that feature. So in Homebrew 1.1.6, I used to edit `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.sh` to remove the root check (the one that said it's "extremely dangerous") so I could run `brew` as root.

The newer version of Homebrew still works with that but keeps reverting the `brew.sh` file back every time after I run `brew`, even if I `chmod 500` it. I could write a script to change it then run `brew` automatically, but I'm not sure if this will always work and don't want to take chances. Has anyone found a different method to run Homebrew as root?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to run `brew` as root?  Also, is `sudo` not sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: @Allan `sudo` does run it as root, and it gives me the same "extremely dangerous" error. I want to run as root because it otherwise has problems installing certain packages, especially if anything was installed not through Homebrew (e.g. through `pip`). I've gone down that route many times. Plus it doesn't work properly for multiple users without weird workarounds unless I install everything as root.

Comment: $ su -> $ brew whateveryouwant ?

Comment: Building a software package as `root` is risky. Even building a package without a package manager, you would build the package as a non-privilege user (yourself) then install the package as `root` with `sudo`. Package managers such as Fink and MacPorts both build with their own non-privilege users then install as `root`. Homebrew does not have such a mechanism.

Comment: @fd0 Understandable, but I'm willing to take the risk; they can do pretty much the same amount of damage without root on my personal computer anyway. But why doesn't Homebrew just install with root like the others do? Their current approach of installing system files as a specific user has ruined my permissions many times.

Comment: @StrawHara If I do that, it detects that it's being run as root and stops.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see the issue on my end wherein the `brew.sh` file is getting reverted after modifying it and then running a `brew` command. So I can run `sudo brew whatever` and `brew whatever` in tandem just fine. My `brew --version` output is thus: `Homebrew 1.2.1-98-g803f9cbf7b-dirty

Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision d3d6; last commit 2017-05-28)`

FYI, I modified my `brew.sh` file to comment out all lines in the `check-run-command-as-root` function and placed a single `return` statement at the top of the function instead.

Comment: @GDP2 I updated to Homebrew 1.2.1 (though mine isn't "dirty" for some reason) and did what you suggested, and I can run `sudo brew ...` multiple times, but it "updates" homebrew if I `sudo brew install ...` and overwrites the hack, so it goes back to the old problem.

Comment: Also tried git committing my change in /usr/local/Homebrew, no luck. Maybe I can make SIP lock the brew.sh file for writing, even for root? :D

Comment: @sudo Hmm, that's very odd. I tried doing a `brew install` and it went on without a hitch, i.e., it left `brew.sh` unmodified and installed fine (possibly unrelated sidenote: I had to first `export HOMEBREW_NO_SANDBOX=true` to get the install to complete correctly). Before protecting the file with SIP you might try `sudo chflags schg /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.sh` along with the `chmod 500` that you did. That will, according to `man chflags`, "set the system immutable flag (super‐user only)".

Comment: To clarify my last comment: I did a `brew install` under `sudo -s` and it went on without a hitch.

Comment: Yes, I know this is old.  SO would probably not like a duplicate.  So here's my addendum.  I completely understand the need for non-root install... but it seems overkill to not allow root to execute "brew leaves --installed-on-request" - which is simply a query to find out what's installed.  Even that fails with the same error.  I have a script intended to document all installed products (PECL, APT, BREW PIP) and for some of these (APT) root is required.  If root is forbidden for brew, then I don't see a clean way to run this all in one script.  Advice?  (It's used on a variety of systems.)

Comment: @Dennis Idk if this helps you, but MacPorts simply runs as root. I don't use brew anymore.

Comment: Thanks @StrawHara.  I chose homebrew after researching the available installers - only installing begrudgingly because it seemed I had no choice but to use some alternate (non-native) installation product.  (A new layer of indirection, if you will.) 
 Now it looks like MacPorts is filling that role.  Next week, maybe something else.  Seems we have to be at the tops of our games to keep software running anymore, and reliability is out the window.  I'm opposed to jumping ship for the solution-of-the-moment.  I do value and appreciate your reply though; I may have no choice but to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After making your change to the script, try setting the immutable flag on brew.sh.

```
chflags uchg /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.sh
```

I have not tested. As a general rule, I do not give root to applications whose developers are begging me not to.

Comment: I also agree with Jason. There is a reason they say not to run brew as root. Mostly because they are the devs and i'lll trust them with their software. Also, unlike macports, which last time i checked still requires that, brew doesn't need or want root permissions so if you screw something up it most likely wont bork your whole system. Everything is contained in your user account and no need to be messing around with sudo.

Comment: Confirmed working, thanks. It takes some time to attempt to update the first time, but later `sudo brew install`s run as normal.

Comment: There isn't much to mess up and render a system unusable with the packages I'd be installing on a Mac. Anyway, I can restore my system within 30 minutes. Cleaning up my user is a lot harder, and many things straight up don't work unless installed system-wide, as I explain in the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

Typical users shouldn't do this, but you're not typical are you?

Two issues:

1. You can't stop root. If you insist on using root, then root can overwrite `brew.sh` no matter what.
2. You can't stop `brew`, after all, you're talking about running `brew`.

So we'll work with that. Let's setup an alias to copy over `brew.sh` then run `brew`.

```
alias brew='cp /<modified>/brew.sh /<actuall>/brew.sh; /usr/local/bin/brew'
```

(Fix the paths to match your system).

Now all you need to do is:

```
sudo brew <arguments>
```

(It'll become root, copy over `brew.sh`, then run `brew` as root with arguments, afterwards `brew` will overwrite `brew.sh` and you'll be ready to do it all over again)

Note: You could put `sudo` into the alias too, but this way feels better because you'll be prompted for a password every time.

Typically you can't use `setuid` (`chmod u+s`) to root on shell scripts, for security.  Perl has a separate program `suidperl` that could be installed and could escalate user privilege, but such solutions are a bit deep for a quick answer.